# Why is "caption:" being included in the rendered string instead of triggering caption-like behavior?

Tags: formatting, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, caption

I am working at populating some text on a Kindle cover. At present `convert` seems to be taking `caption:` to be the beginning of the text I've rendered. The present invocation reads:

```
convert kindle-cover.jpg -font "Georgia" -pointsize 150 -size 320x -gravity South -annotate +0+100 caption:'C.J.S. Hayward' workbench.jpg
```

The text is, as desired, centered near the bottom of the image, and the font size isn't perfect, either. However, I have tried several invocations like `caption:`, `-caption`, etc., and I don't seem to be getting caption-like behavior.

Although not relevant to the author name on the cover, I want to allow titles that show graceful caption-like behavior, including soft wrapping and dynamic resizing if the title the user entered needs to be wrapped.

What can / should I be doing differently to get caption, instead of label, behavior?

Thanks,

**--UPDATE--** @Bonzo suggested I provide my ImageMagick version. The version is:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-07-31 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

The machine is running the current version of Linux Mint.

[image: Sample image]

Comment: You should read the tag descriptions.

Comment: I believe you need to make an image with caption and then add that image to your cover. If you would like to confirm your IM version I am sure somebody can help with your problem.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I've read the bulk of http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption, up to the experimental parts. If you are just going to tell me to read documentation, I'd appreciate if you could provide a link. (I just ran a `convert --help` and saw another approach, tried it, and found it didn't work either).

Comment: You're missing my point - the [convert] tag is in the process of being burninated and should not have been used here.

Comment: @EJoshuaS, I'm sorry that I missed your point. The word 'tag' is used in many settings, and in coming to grips with many-featured software, I ran mentally through a few definitions I could recall of 'tag' in relation to ImageMagick. I didn't realize that you meant 'SO tag' as opposed to offering me advice requested on usage of ImageMagick `convert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use both -annotate and caption: in the same command line in ImageMagick. Try using one or the other. For example here are 3 different methods: -annnotate, label: and caption: with a smaller font size. -annotate write directly on the image. Both label: and caption: create their own separate image that needs to be composited onto your original image.

```
convert kindle-cover.jpg -font "Georgia" -pointsize 72 -gravity south -annotate +0+100 'C.J.S. Hayward' workbench.jpg

convert kindle-cover.jpg \( -size 320x -background none -font "Georgia" -gravity south label:'C.J.S. Hayward' \) -gravity south -geometry +0+100 -compose over -composite workbench.jpg

convert kindle-cover.jpg \( -size 320x -pointsize 72 -background none -font "Georgia" -gravity south caption:'C.J.S. Hayward' \) -gravity south -geometry +0+100 -compose over -composite workbench.jpg
```

EDIT: The latter will wrap, but not the first two. So you need to set the -size 320x to the width you want. As bonzo said, in IM 6, you would need to test your input image size and specify some percentage of that which you want to use. For example, you would have to run it this way in IM 6. Lets say you want the text width to be 1/3 of your image width. In unix syntax, you would do:

```
ww=`convert kindle-cover.jpg -format "%[fx:w/3]" info:`

convert kindle-cover.jpg \( -size ${ww}x -pointsize 72 -background none -font "Georgia" -gravity south caption:'C.J.S. Hayward' \) -gravity south -geometry +0+100 -compose over -composite workbench.jpg
```

In IM 7, you could do

```
magick kindle-cover.jpg \( -size "%[fx:w/3]x" -pointsize 72 -background none -font "Georgia" -gravity south caption:'C.J.S. Hayward' \) -gravity south -geometry +0+100 -compose over -composite workbench.jpg
```

Comment: To get your dimension dynamically in V6 you would need to use something like format and save it into a variable. Whereas in V7 you could do it all in one line.